# Javascript physics easing/attraction maths

Tags: javascript, animation, physics, easing

This is probably best understood by looking at the fiddle, but the general idea that I want to achieve is a smooth scroll, with various 'snapping' attraction points.

The user will scroll with their mouse/trackpad creating a delta value, these are then added together to give a target value, from here I'm easing toward that value (this is to smooth the scroll for people with clicking mouse wheels). Once the scroll has started I want it to snap to various points. I've calculated an attraction force toward these points, but when it is incorporated with my easing from above it doesn't work as desired.

```js
var aEl = document.getElementById('a');
var bEl = document.getElementById('b');

Sketch.create({
  setup: function() {
    this.range = {
      min: 0,
      max: 10000
    };
    this.easing = 0.1;
    this.current = {
      p: 0,
      t: 0,
      f: 0
    };

    this.attractors = [];
    this.attractionRadius = (this.range.max / 5);

    for (var i = 0, x = 0; x = i * (this.range.max / 4), i < 5; i++) {
      this.attractors.push(x);
    }

    window.addEventListener('mousewheel', this.onMouse.bind(this));
  },

  draw: function() {
    var w = (this.current.p / this.range.max) * this.width;
    this.fillStyle = 'black';
    this.fillRect(0, 0, w, this.height);

    this.attractors.forEach(function(attractor) {
      var x = (attractor / this.range.max) * this.width;
      this.beginPath();
      this.arc(x, this.height, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
      this.fillStyle = 'red';
      this.fill();
    }.bind(this));
  },

  update: function() {
    var _this = this;

    this.attractors.forEach(function(attractor, index) {
      var delta = attractor - _this.current.p;
      var absDelta = Math.abs(delta);

      if (absDelta < _this.attractionRadius) {
        // calculate force toward each attraction point.
        _this.current.f += delta * (1 - absDelta / _this.attractionRadius);
      }
    });

    console.log(this.current, (this.current.t - this.current.p) * this.easing);

    // add the easing to our forces, I think this is where the error lies?
    this.current.f += (this.current.t - this.current.p) * this.easing;
    this.current.p += this.current.f;

    //reset the forces.
    this.current.f = 0;
  },

  // set the target from the users scroll position, limited to the range set above.
  onMouse: function(event) {
    var delta = event.wheelDeltaY;

    this.current.t += delta;
    this.current.t =
      this.current.t < this.range.min ? this.range.min :
      this.current.t > this.range.max ? this.range.max :
      this.current.t;

    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/soulwire/sketch.js/master/js/sketch.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/letsgojuno/xgqcvmbo/8/ jsfiddle link.

Comment: "doesn't work as desired" implies that we know what you desire, which is hardly the case here. Please elaborate how exactly the code goes wrong and what you expect it to do.

Comment: **"the general idea that I want to achieve is a smooth scroll, with various 'snapping' attraction points"**. I'd like it to scroll smoothly, then be attracted to the attraction points (marked with red circle). It's like a linear particle attraction system. So imagine the scroll bar as a particle that moves when the user scrolls but is attracted to the points. With out the input from the users scroll, it should come to rest at one of the points.